# How to set MAC address on (HTC Desire) Android terminal emulator?

Tags: htc-desire, terminal, mac-address

I typed into the terminal this:

> ip link set eth0 address
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

the XX for my numbers and so on.

But it says permission denied.

Source: http://androidforums.com/incredible-tips-tricks/78668-how-spoof-mac-address.html

Comment: I doubt Android supports this, there's no legitimate reason for changing the MAC address.  Any method to do so would also be chip-specific I think.

Comment: I merged your old question with this one so you should be able to edit it now and clean it up a bit, all under your new ID.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like your terminal doesn't have root access. Is your phone rooted? and did you type `su` to get to the root user first? On my phone you can tell if you're using root privileges by checking the prompt, `$` = no root, `#` = root.

Comment: i didn't root..

Comment: As far as I know, you need root to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Root is needed so if you have that turn on your wi-fi and write

```
su
iplink set eth0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

and it's done.

("iplink" without space between)

Answer (score -1):

Check http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1525230

You actually need to change some stuff in the bcm4239 driver to allow it to read the mac address from somewhere else. The above kernel reads the file /data/local/mac.dat.

Comment: An answer which requires the reader to go to a different site to get any useful information isn't really an answer.